# DevExpress MVC Gridview create filter only over visible rows

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview, filter, devexpress

Seeing that all other related topics have 0 or 1 answers, I'm not very confident about this, but let's give it a go...
First: I'm not asking in the devexpress forums because the paying user is somebody else, and getting their permission to post is a mess.

I have the following setup in a lot of the website's views: a filtering box (let's call it Our Filter), and a GridView beneath it. The filtering box sends the form to the grid's callback function, which filters the viewmodel and re-renders the grid. In quite a few, we have the Filter Builder option to create filters.

Our problem is that the filters created work well, but ignore Our Filter. We would like the filters created to take Our Filter into account, basically only filter over the visible rows.

A concrete example: we have a grid we can filter over Bank (bank is not a column of the grid), this calls the grid's callback which filters the viewmodel and refreshes the grid (partialview), if in this grid we have 2 rows with a column X which both have value Y. If I create a filter with the Filter Builder, with column X equal to Z, it works, but it gets them from the complete list, not the filtered one (these two rows for example, don't show).

Is there a way to resolve this? Any ideas are welcome.

** EDIT **
Our index controller returns a viewmodel with the complete list of entity User, and shows a gridview with the User list and a few properties, for example the name and Add Date. It also shows a form above the grid to filter the users by addDate, you can put a range and submit.
This submit calls the gridview's callback function, which is another function in the controller that creates a viewmodel with a filtered list of users (using LINQ, only getting those elements from the DB), and returns a partialview of the Grid, only re-rendering the grid.
Once it's re-rendered, I want to use the devexpress filter builder in the bottom of the grid. When I put a rule into it, and accept, it works *but* it shows ALL the users that comply with it, not the ones in the list shown in the grid (the ones filtered by date).
I hope this clarifies the two types of filters.

Comment: You could use LINQ to search the data source that populates the gridview dependant upon the 'filter' applied. Provided the hidden fields are in the data source you will be able to return the data you need.

Comment: To what filter are you referring? We're using it for Our Filter, it works fine. But it seems the devexpress filter creator re-does the query or something, because it's ignoring Our Filter's backend function, it simply does the work over the unfiltered original elements. Thanks!

Comment: It's difficult to see what you are asking. You have said 'filter' too many time for me to process. So you have a 'box' that refines a set of search results that are shown in the gridview? If so, why not just use Linq to power the filtering?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your help, I've tried to clarify the situation, hope it helps. We do use LINQ for the filter we can, the other one is devexpress' and we don't think we can modify it.